# Formatting a column with pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm new to Pandas and Python.

We have a firewall application that parses out our ACLs in CSV format.
The problem is 
-it provides way too  much info
-the format of the data makes the info useless

We've been editing these queries by hand until now.

I've figured out how to use pandas to "pull" the columns we need.
Now I need to reconfigure one of the columns to the proper format.

So far my code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
    f=pd.read_csv("/Volumes/Untitled/ACL-SOURCE.csv")
    keep_col = ['Device name','Source','Destination','Service']
    new_f = f[keep_col]

# this pulls the 4 columns I ned out of the original 20 column CSV.

# If I do a print of 'new_f" i get the following:

   Device name      Source    Destination        Service
0  ACL-NAME-V1     ABC-123        MEC-KLM        ssh/tcp
1  ACL-NAME-V1     ABC-123        MEC-KLM       3306/tcp
2  ACL-NAME-V1     MEC-456        MEC-KLM        ssh/tcp
3  ACL-NAME-V1     MEC-456        MEC-KLM       3306/tcp
4  ACL-NAME-V1     MEC-456        MEC-KLM       4444/tcp
5  ACL-NAME-V1     MEC-456        MEC-KLM       8888/tcp
6  ACL-NAME-V1     MEC-456        MEC-KLM  4567-4568/tcp
7  ACL-NAME-V1     MEC-456        MEC-KLM           icmp
```

At this point what I want to do is format the last row to
Move the tcp in front of the port number and remove the '/'.
the end result will be from ssh/tcp to tcp ssh

for some reason I can't wrap my head around this.

Please help. Thanks,

Comment: I don't really understand what you want that "last row" vs column? to look like? Give an example? of what it is (which I guess we have) and what you want? And is this only the last line that has icmp? Is the issue always last line or lines that have icmp? or is it ssh related? Show original raw text?

Answer (score 1):

apply will apply a function to everything in your series.
The thing is to make the function.  I called it switch and 'x' is all the data in the series.

```
def switch(x):
    a = x.split('/')
    a.reverse()
    return ' '.join(a)

df['Service'].apply(switch)
```

Comment: This works.but how do I add the newly formatted 'service' back to my table?

Comment: You can use df['Service'] = df['Service'].apply(switch)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to create new column with data from Service column processed:

```
import pandas as pd
    f=pd.read_csv("/Volumes/Untitled/ACL-SOURCE.csv")
    f.assign(srv = f['Service'].split('/')[1] + " " + f['Service'].split('/')[0])
    keep_col = ['Device name','Source','Destination','srv']
    new_f = f[keep_col]
```

Comment: You would get an index error when you hit that line 7.  Line 7 service doesn't have a '/' to split.